# Content-Type header is text/html when uploading a file to the server using a multipart request only in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm sending a multipart request to a server in order to upload a file, however this is working only on Android, when it comes to iOS I get an Internal Server Error with a status code 500. When I print the headers on Android the content type is application json, but on iOS the content type is text/html. Is this a server-side problem? or should I set any other header in the multipart request besides authorization header?

This is the code of the request

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadFileToEvent(File file, int eventId) async {
  var stream = http.ByteStream(file.openRead());
  stream.cast();
  var length = await file.length();

  String url = '$_url/event/$eventId/media/';

  final _header = <String, String>{
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _prefs.token,
  };

  var uri = Uri.parse(url);

  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

  var multipartFileSign = http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length, filename: basename(file.path));

  request.files.add(multipartFileSign);

  request.headers.addAll(_header);

  var response = await request.send();

  final resp = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
}
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to use the `http.MultipartFile.fromPath()` convenience constructor. It also takes an optional parameter `contentType` that allows you to specify the type of that file.

Comment: I also tried that way, using mime_type and http_parser to get the correct content type, but it didn't work.